# Identical Javascript doesnt work in both IE and Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome

Isnt it following two script is identical? but they seems to contradict in different browser.

--works in IE9 but not chrome

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var el=document.getElementById('myLink');

window.onload = function(){
  measurePlt();
  //$("#myLink").trigger('click');
  el.trigger('click');
};

el.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

--works in chrome but not in IE

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
  measurePlt();
  $("#myLink").trigger('click');  
};

$("#myLink")..click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

can someone pls help?

Comment: Should the second one have a double period on this line? `$("#myLink")..click(function(e) {`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#myLink")..click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Change the above piece of code from PART II to

```
$("#myLink").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
});
```